# How to pass latitude and longitude to another function - swift location

Tags: ios, swift, location, cllocationmanager

I'm having trouble passing the latitude and longitude to a function where I'm building the api url to get some weather data back. I know that I'm missing something to call the location function before calling the weather function. Basically my thought was to get the location first and store the latitude and longitude in some variables, and then call the weather function in which I use those values.

I've provided comments for my chain of thought.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var locManager = CLLocationManager()

// created these to store the latitude and longitude, are they necessary?
var lat : Double!
var long : Double!

// viewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Location Manager - I ask for permission and then start updating
    locManager.delegate = self
    locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    // Need something here to call the function where I get the lat and long
    //

    // This is where I get weather data using the api
    getCurrentWeatherData()
}

// Latitude and Longitude - I'm getting the lat and long
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    var locValue : CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location.coordinate
    locManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    lat = locValue.latitude
    long = locValue.longitude
}

// I'm using this function to build the api url and get weather data.
func getCurrentWeatherData() -> Void {
    let baseURL = NSURL(string: "https://api path here/\(apiKey)/")
    let forecastURL = NSURL(string: "\(lat),\(long)", relativeToURL: baseURL)

// more code here //

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of storing the variables and trying to guess when they've been set, you should just call the function within your `locationManager` handler:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
  var locValue : CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location.coordinate
  locManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
  provideWeatherForLocation(locValue)
  // or:
  provideWeatherForLocation(latitude: locValue.latitude, longitude: locValue.longitude)
}
```